System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost from with .NET Core app
I've got a .NET Framework 4.7 C# library that uses System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost, which is not available in the .NET Core framework.
When I call the library from within a .NET Framework 4.7 application, the ServiceHost initializes just fine.
If I call the same library from a .NET Core 3.1 application, it fails with an error

System.TypeLoadException: 'Could not load type 'System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost' from assembly 'System.ServiceModel

Loading nuget packages like System.ServiceModel.Primitives does not fix it.
What options do I have to make this work?

One option would be to download the code and build it for .NET Core 3.1.

Could you provide some more information regarding your project? Are you trying to work with legacy WCF services?

Yes it's indeed a WCF service

@ErwinKloibhofer Equivalent of System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost (Old WCF framework run on .Net Framework) is CoreWCF.ServiceHost (New WCF framework run on .NET Core)

@ErwinKloibhofer look at here CoreWCF https://github.com/CoreWCF/CoreWCF

Microsoft released CoreWCF in order to enable .NET Framework WCF Services to be used in .Net Core.
You'll need to use the CoreWCF.Primitives, and CoreWCF.Http packages at a minimum.
The code for your actual services should be able to be kept unchanged, as there shouldn't be any huge changes, simply make sure you update the using references so they point at CoreWCF.
You will then need to update your Program.cs file to include your service's bindings by adding the following lines:
builder.Services.AddServiceModelServices().AddServiceModelMetadata();

var app = builder.Build(); // Make sure the rest of the lines are added after this line

app.UseServiceModel(builder =>
{
builder.AddService((serviceOptions) => { })
// Add a BasicHttpBinding at a specific endpoint
.AddServiceEndpoint<YourService, IYourService>(new BasicHttpBinding(), "/EchoService/basichttp")
// Add a WSHttpBinding with Transport Security for TLS
.AddServiceEndpoint<YourService, IYourService>(new WSHttpBinding(SecurityMode.Transport), "/YourService/WSHttps");
});
var serviceMetadataBehavior = app.Services.GetRequiredService();
serviceMetadataBehavior.HttpGetEnabled = true;

Of course, you'll want to replace IYourService and YourService with your own versions that include your DataContacts and ServiceContracts.
You can find a blog post with an example implementation from Microsoft here.
